# Расчитать и сравнить зарплаты в отделах

Tags: sql

Всем привет есть такое задание - вернуть всех сотрудников для которых верно, что
зарплата < средняя в отделе 1
и
зарплата < средняя в отделе 2
и
...
зарплата < средняя в отделе N
то есть не просто взять общую среднюю по всей фирме и сравнить с зп работника, а взять каждую среднюю по всем отделам и с ними всеми сравнить зп нашего сотрудников
Вот мой код - он не работает

```
SELECT firstnme
FROM employee
WHERE salary < (
        SELECT ROUND(AVG(salary), 2), workdept
        FROM employee
        GROUP BY workdept)
```

работает только нахождение средней зп по конкретном отделу

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(salary), 2), workdept FROM employee GROUP BY workdept
```

В чем мои ошибки?

Comment: @Akina "взять минимальную из них" - минимальную из отдела что ли? что то я суть не уловил

Comment: Да может уже научишься join использовать вместо этой дичи?

Answer (score 0):

Зарплата сотрудника меньше наименьшей из средних по отделу.

```sql
SELECT firstnme
FROM employee
WHERE salary < (
        SELECT AVG(salary)
        FROM employee
        GROUP BY workdept
        ORDER BY AVG(salary) ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Зарплата сотрудника меньше средней по его отделу.

```sql
SELECT t1.firstnme
FROM employee t1
JOIN ( SELECT AVG(salary) salary, workdept
       FROM employee
       GROUP BY workdept ) t2 USING (workdept)
WHERE t1.salary < t2.salary
```

Comment: значит в этом примере мы находим сотрудников с зарплатой меньше средней по их разным отделам? Вы не могли бы обьяснить ORDER BY AVG(salary) ASC LIMIT 1? или это оно и есть о чем вы написали ранее?

Comment: мой подзапрос показывает среднюю в каждом отделе, Ваш поздапрос показывает минимальную среднюю. так?

Comment: Запрос не проходит, я наверное не правильно понял задание вот как оно звучит Return all employees for which salary less than average salary in each department

Comment: @4y4yHDpuk *я наверное не правильно понял задание* Конечно, нет. Тут чётко говорится, что зарплата сотрудника должна быть меньше средней по **его** отделу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139921/discussion-between-4y4yhdpuk-and-akina).

Comment: Да, оно. Теперь буду пытаться это все переложить на пример в количественных предикатах. Спасибо огромное за Вашу помощь, если бы все так помогали новичкам как Вы - новички бы мастерами становились...

Comment: @4y4yHDpuk А вот если бы ещё новички не ленились помечать ответы как принятые - было бы вообще классно... у Вас как минимум 5 таких вопросов - с непринятыми ответами.

Comment: я перерегаюсь и буду проставлять, за одно остальные проставлю

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос уже почти готов. Главное, что вы забыли/не знали, так это про функцию ALL. Также в подзапросе для сравнения требуется выводить 1 столбец, а не 2 (имею ввиду workdept). Таким образом будет сравниваться зарплата каждого сотрудника со средней зарплатой каждого отдела. И если зарплата сотрудника будет меньше всех средних зарплат каждого отдела, то мы его увидим в выборке.

Ниже приведен исправленный вариант:

```
SELECT firstnme
FROM employee
WHERE salary < ALL (
        SELECT ROUND(AVG(salary), 2)
        FROM employee
        GROUP BY workdept)
```